# removing based on filtered value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a parsed_JSON with directories and frequencies(cleaning frequency of the directory).

I want to remove the section if all of is sub directory frequency is set to "not".

For example:

```
[ { label: 'Offices',
     rows: [ { freq: '1w'},{ freq: '2w'},{ freq: 'not'} ]  },
  { label: 'Kitchen and community areas – Extras',
    rows: [ { freq: 'not'},{ freq: 'not'},{ freq: 'not'} ] 
},
]
```

in this case the section labeled 'Kitchen and community areas – Extras' should be removed.

I achieved this with the following code:

```
  const mapped_sections      = _.map(parsed_json, section => ({
        label   : section.label,
        rows    : _.map(section.rows, row => _.merge({}, default_row, row)),
    }));

    const sections = _.forEach(mapped_sections, (section, i) => {
        let not_length_count = 0;
        _.forEach(section, (rows) => {
            _.forEach(rows, (row) => {
                if (row.freq === "not") {
                    not_length_count += 1;
                }
            });
            if (not_length_count === rows.length) {
                mapped_sections.splice(i, 1);
            }
        });
    });
```

But I want to refactor it with ES6 methods like `filter()` and by only mapping through `mapped_sections`

I've been trying but got stuck here:

```
const sections      = _.map(parsed_json, (section, i) => {
        const test = ((section.rows.filter(item => item.freq === "not"))
                && (section.rows.filter(item => item.freq === "not").length === section.rows.length)
            ? section.rows.slice(i, 1)
            : section.rows
        );
        return (
            section.label,
            _.map(test, row => _.merge({}, default_row, row))
        );
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a *not `!`* on rows of elements with [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function like follows:

```js
const myList = [
  {
    label: 'Offices',
    rows: [{ freq: '1w'},{ freq: '2w'},{ freq: 'not'}]
  },
  {
    label: 'Kitchen and community areas – Extras',
    rows: [{ freq: 'not'},{ freq: 'not'},{ freq: 'not'}] 
  },
]

const result = myList.filter(el => !el.rows.every(r => r.freq === 'not'))

console.log(result)
```

Items with all `freq`s `not` are filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

let me know if it works

```
let arr = [ { label: 'Offices',
     rows: [ { freq: '1w'},{ freq: '2w'},{ freq: 'not'} ]  },
  { label: 'Kitchen and community areas – Extras',
    rows: [ { freq: 'not'},{ freq: 'not'},{ freq: 'not'} ] 
},
]

arr.filter(ar => {
    let rowCount = 0;
    ar.rows.forEach(row => {
        row.freq === 'not' ? rowCount++: rowCount;
    })
    return rowCount !== ar.rows.length
}) 
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

combine `_.find` and `_.some`

```js
let data = [{
    label: 'Offices',
    rows: [{
      freq: '1w'
    }, {
      freq: '2w'
    }, {
      freq: 'not'
    }]
  },
  {
    label: 'Kitchen and community areas – Extras',
    rows: [{
      freq: 'not'
    }, {
      freq: 'not'
    }, {
      freq: 'not'
    }]
  }
];

const result = _.filter(data, item => _.some(item.rows, (x) =>  x.freq !== 'not'))

console.log({
  result
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```